# C++ Pointer trouble with File I/O

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, file-io

I am writing a function that takes in a output target file and a couple of other arguments. I am currently having trouble with converting types between the argument passed in and using it in the fopen_s() method.

```
FILE* outputf;

void myfunc(FILE* fin, CString finpath,...)
{

  outputf = fopen_s(&fin, finpath, "w");
  .......
}
```

I've been stuck on this for a while and could use some help on this one. I am developing in Visual Studio 2008

Thanks

Comment: It's good idea to show errors/warnings. Otherwise we can't help much and it'll take too long to guess.

Comment: Do you get a compile error, or is it a run-time problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I found my answer. Turns out that fopen_S doesn't allow shared access to the FILE* specified for opening. I had to use _fsopen instead and that solced my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just have to cast `CString` to `LPCTSTR`:

```
outputf = fopen_s(&fin, (LPCTSTR)finpath, "w");
```